# ゲームサーバーで、不正なリクエストを防ぐ方法は？

Tags: security

例えば、ブラウザ上でプレイできるテトリスを実装したとして、そのランキングをサーバー上で集計するとします。

ユーザーがプレイを終えたタイミングで、ゲームサーバーにスコア情報を通信しますが、それが、ユーザーが例えばブラウザ上の DevConsole を開くなどして、通信先を特定し、スコア情報更新 api を特定し、そこに任意のスコアを入力してサーバーに送信することで、任意の点数をサーバーに登録できしてしまうような気がします。

#### 質問

ゲームサーバーで例えばランキングを集計する場合、不正なリクエストを防ぐにあたって、どのような手段が取られますか？

Comment: Game Developmentにはまさにそのような話題のためのタグ [`leaderboards`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaderboards?sort=votes)なんてのがあるみたいです(`anti-cheat`タグと組み合わせてみてみると似た質問が見つかります)。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

数コマンドごとに、プレイヤーのコマンドと得点をサーバーに送信して、サーバー側でシミュレーションした得点と一致するか検証すると良さそうです

Answer (score 1):

@Liamovwv さんのおっしゃるように、クライアント側の、最終結果に至る途中のデータも送信させ、それをサーバー側で検証する、というのが一般的なそうです。

また、ゲームの種類によっては、ゲームのステータスなどはすべてサーバー側で管理してしまって、クライアントはただインタラクティブなレンダリング・インターフェースの提供に徹するようなアーキテクチャもありうるそうです。

Comment: ただの興味本位ですが、そのあたりの「一般的」「ありうる」の情報はどこかにソースがありますか。

Comment: ほぼほぼ伝聞なので、ソースはない感じです…

Comment: なるほど。わかりました。